# SQL keep reflecting syntax error for getdate when i create table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

> SQL keep reflecting syntax error 
>   "A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "(""
>   Any idea whats wrong? or how to fix it ..?

```
"CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL ,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  'date_created' DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
   UNIQUE (id)
) ";
```

Comment: Fix your tags, is it sql-server or mysql?  I'm guessing it's mysql so use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `GETDATE()`.

Comment: The syntax will be different between MYSQL and SQLServer. So which are you **actually using**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GETDATE()` doesn't work in MySQL, replace it with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and you're golden, assuming you're MySQL is up-to-date, if it isn't the `DATETIME` type cannot use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as it's default and you'd need to use the `TIMESTAMP` type instead

Answer (score 0):

The error is on `GETDATE()`, i personally use timestamp and i think you want to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one
>   exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a
>   function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot
>   set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such
>   as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP or (as of MySQL
>   5.6.5) DATETIME column. See Section 11.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME”.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

So your create statement should be

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```